# Tuple Enum in Java

Tags: java

I'm very new in Java and were wondering and didn't find anything about it.

Can you create enum tuple ?

```
public enum Status {OPEN : "1", CLOSED: "2", DELETED: "3"}
```

I will need to access both "OPEN" or "1"

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected usage/use case in code?

Comment: Maybe you will find this useful: http://javarevisited.blogspot.gr/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always create a custom constructor for your `enum`..

```
public enum Status {


    OPEN("1"),
    CLOSED("2"),
    DELETED("3");

    private String code;

    public Status(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Then you can access with `Status.OPEN.getCode()`. This functions as an effective mapping between an `enum` type and a `code` value.

Comment: I was writing this, you were first, change Static to Status and it will be perfect :D

Comment: @Sirs One cannot subclass an enum anyway, who cares if it's final or not?

Comment: As I said, it's a style comment. For me it should be final not because of overriding (even if enums could be overridden, it's a private variable so it would not be overridable), but because it's value is not expected to change after it's initial assignment.

Comment: Thanks worked like charm and did not break existing usage of old enum :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
public enum Currency {PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25)};
```

But for this to work you need to define a member variable and a constructor because PENNY (1) is actually calling a constructor which accepts int value , see below example.

```
public enum Currency {
        PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
        private int value;

        private Currency(int value) {
                this.value = value;
        }
};
```

Constructor of enum in java must be private any other access modifier will result in compilation error. Now to get the value associated with each coin you can define a public getValue() method inside java enum like any normal java class. Also semi colon in the first line is optional.

```
 private int getValue() { return value; }
```

and get values like this:-

```
PENNY.getValue(); //returns int 1
```

[Refrence:](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz36JFUySa7)

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @christopher cover only first part. Creating ENUM.

You will need one more method that match code with enum value:

```
public static Status byCode(String code){                            
    for(Status s : Status.values()) {                         
        if (s.code.equals(code)) {                            
            return s;                                         
        }                                                     
    }                                                         

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Code does not match");
}
```

now you can get enum value by name and by code.

Comment: Thanks for this also needed it ;)